# Bounty end warnings off by 43 minutes

Tags: bug, bounties, notifications, email-notification

I received an email a few minutes ago noting that my bounty had expired. On clicking through to the question I'd posted it on, it said there was still over half an hour left. The notification in my inbox lined up with the email, both about 43 minutes early.

That's great that you warn me, but it's confusing as can be to be told something before it's actually true. I suggest either fixing the verbiage in the notices or waiting to send it out until it's actually true!

[image: screenshot of notification + bounty]